# Python: using either command line or import

Tags: python

```
def nearbin():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "choose near bin")
    parser.add_argument("-bin",  type=int,action = "store", default = "10", help="bin number")   
    args = parser.parse_args()   
    bin = args.bin 
    print bin
    return f(bin)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    nearbin()
```

In command line, I can use "python test.py -bin 10" to run the program

If I want to `import test` in another python script and use function `nearbin(bin)` in another script, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My usual approach:

```
def nearbin(bin):
    ...

def main(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)
    ...
    args = parser.parse_args(args)

    nearbin(args.bin)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

This lets you support direct command-line invocation (`./script.py -bin 20`), invocation with command line args (`main("-bin 20".split())`), and programmatic invocation (`nearbin(20)`).

Answer (score 2):

Then you should parse the command line arguments inside the `__main__` check and pass them to `nearbin`, something like this:

```
def nearbin(bin):
    print bin
    return f(bin)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "choose near bin")
    parser.add_argument("-bin",  type=int,action = "store", default = "10", help="bin number")   
    args = parser.parse_args()   
    bin = args.bin 
    nearbin(bin)
```